# Positioning responsive divs over video following aspect ratio 16:9

Tags: html, css, html5-video, aspect-ratio

**TL;DR: How to make the gray and blue square exactly cover the fire and logs in the video no matter how the window is resized? (The video is always in aspect-ratio 16:9 in the window)**

I have a page with just a button in the top-left corner and a video that fills the window. The thing I want to do is to add divs at specific locations over "items" in the video with the goal of adding onclick events to them. On the picture, they are shown as the gray and blue square covering the fire and logs, respectively.

[image: Fullscreen of the bonfire-video with a gray and blue square on top of it.]

The problems emerge when the **window is resized significantly narrow**:

[image: Narrow window with the grey and blue squares being excessively tall.]

**Or wide**:

[image: Wide window with the grey and blue squares being excessively long.]

It happens because I set the width, height, left, and top as percentages of the container div in css. So while the container fills the whole window, the  object will be in its aspect-ratio, causing the grey and blue divs to expand too much or too little.

HTML:

```
<div id="video-container">

    <div id="positioned-div1"></div>

    <div id="positioned-div2"></div>

    <video id="video-obj" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="/media/bonfire.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video-obj {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#video-obj video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#positioned-div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 55%;
    top: 53%;
    width: 24%;
    height: 24%;
    background-color: rgba(38, 0, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

#positioned-div2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 38%;
    top: 45%;
    width: 16%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

- The criterias here are:

  1. The video is always in aspect-ratio, as you can see on the three screenshots.
  2. The gray div always covers the fire, while the blue div always covers the logs.

So to repeat the question: **How to make the gray and blue square exactly cover the fire and logs in the video no matter how the window is resized? (The video is always in aspect-ratio 16:9 in the window)**

Comment: What is centering the video?

Comment: @AHaworth The div container with id "video-container". And then the video fills the window with width and height of 100% while keeping the aspect ratio. I know, it's a bit convoluted, worked after experimenting.